# OSM digitizing road map by shapefile

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I have shapefile with roads. I want to digitize some of the objects in shapefile to OSM, because I allways use OSM shapefiles and I have something to give to. What software should I use? I have JOSM installed. Is it enough?

Comment: I believe that Merkaartor editor can import shapefiles directly but I don't have it installed at the moment and documentation does not mention this feature http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Merkaartor/Documentation. However, it should not be hard to have a try.

Comment: Before doing any sort of import, you should check the OpenStreetMap Import Guidelines. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines

Answer (score 4):

JOSM can not read shapefiles directly.

For that reason I have QGIS installed, where I can view my shapefiles on OSM background via Openlayers plugin.

QGIS is able to export shapefiles of type `point` and `line` to gpx format (which can be loaded into JOSM) as a separate layer with `Save As ...`. The coordinate reference system must be reprojected to WGS84 if necessary. In the options, `FORCE_GPX_TRACK` must be set to `YES`, and `Skip attribute creation` must be checked.

In JOSM, you can download OSM raw data along the gps path, and then start to create new ways and points, or move or extent existing elements. Simply uploading new features is **not** encouraged, because they must fit existing to elements, or been connected to them.

If you have polygon shapefiles, you have to transform them in QGIS to closed lines with `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Polygons to lines` , because gpx format does not know polygons.

Comment: @Andre Joost - JOSM can read shp - you need OpenData plugin and your shp have to be in wgs84.

Answer (score 2):

Shapefiles can be directly loaded in JOSM, after you install opendata plugin. Beware that importing data from shapefile is not considered good as it has to mix the more complex osm data structure. Also you have to consider the source and license of the shapefile. You can only contribute data which is compatible with osm's ODBL license.